# Python-Telegram-Bot: send message through bot in different module

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I'm writing a Telegram bot using the python-telegram-bot library.
The bot should send a message to the user when a new YoutubeChannel is published.
I created a telegram_bot.py in which I created a TelegramBot class.
In this class I have this function:
**telegram_bot.py**

```
def __init__(self):
    self.updater = Updater(token=telegram_token, use_context=True)
    self.dispatcher = self.updater.dispatcher  
    self.updater.start_polling()

def send_message(self, text_message, context: CallbackContext):
    context.bot.send_message(
        chat_id="@<<my username>>", text=text_message)
```

And in the main.py I have a line of code that should send the message usign the aforementioned function, like this:
**main.py**

```
from telegram_bot import TelegramBot  

tg_bot = TelegramBot()
tg_bot.send_message("New video!")
```

But, when I run the code above, I get this error:

> TypeError: send_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'context'

But in the *send_message* definition I already defined the *context*

Answer (score 0):

Solved this way:
**main.py**

```
tg_bot = TelegramBot()
tg_bot.send_message("New video!", context=tg_bot.dispatcher)
```